# Usage of printf and fgets together in a loop

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a simple program which infinitely reads input from the user and then prints it. But there are some problems. It is a simple issue but my Google searches didn't lead me any solution. Here is the code.

```
int main() {

    char pass[32];
    int x=10;

    while (x!=0) {


        printf("\nInput the password: ");
        fgets(pass, sizeof(pass), stdin);

        printf("that is what i read: %s", pass);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter a string longer than 32 characters, it behaves anormally.

```
Input the password: pass
that is what i read: pass

Input the password: passsssss
that is what i read: passsssss

Input the password: passssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
that is what i read: passsssssssssssssssssssssssssss
Input the password: that is what i read: sss

Input the password:
```

You see in the third attempt, it prints the third line automatically. I didn't type the input 'that is what i read: sss'.

Why does that happen?

Comment: "I didn't type the input 'that is what i read: sss'." --> Yes you did, it is the leftover from "passssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" that was not read in the previous `fgets()`.

Comment: `fgets()` reads up to 31 characters and null terminates the string.  If there are more than 31 characters in the line, it leaves the rest for the next input operation, with the result you see.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica How can I clean the leftovers before proceeding with the next iteration? I tried fflush(stdin) and it didn't work.

Comment: When the result of `fgets()` is a full buffer without a `\n`.  Read again until `\n` found or end-of-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets()` does not limit the length of a line a user enters.  `fgets()` limits how much of that line is read.

With too much input, the remainder is left for the next input operation.

---

If input via `fgets()`lacks a `'\n'`, then either

- Entire line was not read, (common enough)
- Input w/o `'\n'` and then end-of-file, (seldom)
- A *null character* was read. (rare)
- Input buffer smaller than 1. (pathological)

Below readily IDs the first 2.

```
// Test if anything was read.
if (fgets(pass, sizeof pass, stdin)) {
  // Was it missing a '\n'?
  if (strchr(pass, '\n') == NULL) {
    // Read rest of line and throw it away
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I read let's say 15 character-long string input to the variable pass, values after the 15th element in the array will be null. Do you know how can I get rid of those null values?

Comment: @FarukD `fgets()` reads a _line_ of input and forms a _string_ (an sequence  of characters with a terminating _null character_).  The values after the _null character_ are unused parts of the array.  Simply do  not read/use  the later portion of the array.

Comment: @FarukD did you mean to say 'get rid of the new line character'?

Comment: @isrnick no, but I can say that as well. It seems like there always exists a newline character at the end of the string. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: @FarukD To lop off a _potential_ `'\n'`, use `pass[strcspn(pass,"\n")] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

The safe solution when using `fgets` would be something like this:

```
if (fgets(pass, sizeof(pass), stdin) != NULL){
    int len = strlen(pass);
    if (len > 0 && pass[len-1] != '\n'){
        int ch;
        while ((ch=getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
if (fgets(pass, sizeof(pass), stdin) != NULL){
    if (strcspn(pass, "\n") == sizeof(pass) - 1){
        int ch;
        while ((ch=getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    }
}
```

You need to check if there is a new line character `\n` in the string, if there isn't then there is excess characters left in the `stdin` that must be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You limited your input variable to 32 characters, so in order to stop it from doing that, simply make pass[32] bigger.

Comment: I can still enter strings larger than the buffer size, can't I? That doesn't change the situation.

Comment: @Faruk That's the problem with those legacy C APIs: they are hard to use correctly. It's better to use Unix/POSIX APIs where they are available.

Comment: You're still reading from the standard input, and it just reads from that stream on the next read operation.